# django & postgres timezone localtime vs utc

Tags: python, django, postgresql, time

I save a datetime to my postgres db, when I then display it on my website it's wrong...

In my models.py:

```
datetime_start = models.DateTimeField()
```

In postgres the time is saved like this: utc+2h:

[image]

In my django I made following settings:

```
USE_TZ = True

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
```

In my template I get the time, for testing I display once the utc and once the localtime:

```
<th> Start </th>
<td>{{activity.datetime_start |utc|date:"d.m.Y H:i"}}</td>
<td>{{activity.datetime_start |localtime|date:"d.m.Y H:i"}}</td>
```

And here the output on my website:

[image]

Why this output is wrong? The utc time should be: 06:00

And the localtime should be: 08:00

I'm confused, what did I make wrong with the timezones and times? Does django interpret the postgres time wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found now the solution. I saved the time in the wrong format in postgres.
Because the time I saved is already a UTC time, I also have to set the timezone...

The data['value'] object is already a UTC time, so I added the timezone to it:

```
import pytz

start_datetime_tz = data['value'].replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```